# Python: Trying to save and load lists from a .txt file

Tags: python, list, storage

So I've been working on this assignment for a few weeks now and this is the last hurdle which has taken me a few days and I'm still stuck. What I'm trying to do is save about 10 List files to a .txt file and then load them up. The lists contain strings and integers and to separate the different lists (or characters because this is supposed to be an RPG game lol).
So I have a function to save everything

```
def save(data):
    with open("FightcraftParty.txt", "w") as f:
        for Char in data:
            for stat in Char:
                f.write(str(stat) +"\n")
            #f.write(list(Char)+"\n")
    print("Saved to FightcraftParty.txt")
```

And I have a load function

```
def load(L):
    for j in L:
        j = []
    i = 0
    with open("FightcraftParty.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            try:
                if int(line)==420:
                    L[i].append(420)
                    i+=1
                else:
                    L[i].append(int(line))
            except:
                L[i].append(str(line))
```

Either of these may be chosen so it's not an issue of them overlapping. However, when I do this I get an 'IndexError: list index out of range' and I can't fully work out why. I have rewritten the load() function several times and each time it gives the same outcome. Although there was one time when it added all the items to one list.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is `L`? is it an empty list?

Comment: Your first for-loop in the load function does nothing - what was the intent there?

Comment: Why not save the data as a json file instead? This way you can use python's in-built json parser to read/write the data rather than having to manually parse the text.

Comment: just a question since you mentioned that its for a game, do you need to store the flies as a .txt ? There are a few other methods of storing data such that it persists. The JSON suggestion by scotty is one such method; you could also save the lists as a messagePack. Or if you are feeling lazy and just want to save whole objects by themselves you could use pickle (I would not suggest this unless storing whole objects makes a big difference)

Comment: L is a list of lists. The first loop clears the List to just 10 empty list. I'll have a look into changing into json. Thanks all. I'll have a look into using messagePack

Comment: It's not worked yet, I'm still getting index error. Does anyone know why that might be